# android JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: obj == null, but have no JNI code [libc.so] abort

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I'm getting tons of crashes posted to the Android Play Console, with no reference to my code. It's starting to impact reviews, and I'm up +200% crash rate. I've spent about 2 weeks on this with research, debugging and refactor/cleanups. It does not crash on my two phones or emulators. Tried with various different android versions.
It says: `JNI DETECTED ERROR`
However I use no JNI at all.

```
[libc.so] abort
SIGABRT
```

This is what I see in the Android Console crash reports:

```
JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: obj == null

pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.xxxxxx.myapp <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x0000000000050f28  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164)
  #01  pc 0x00000000006d2a4c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+704)
  #02  pc 0x0000000000016ea8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+80)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000016450  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+352)
  #04  pc 0x0000000000445224  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JavaVMExt::JniAbort(char const*, char const*)+1612)
  #05  pc 0x00000000005dde2c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::JNI<false>::CallVoidMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, std::__va_list)+500)
  #06  pc 0x00000000000b15c4  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (_JNIEnv::CallVoidMethod(_jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...)+120)
  #07  pc 0x0000000000404034  /data/misc/apexdata/com.android.art/dalvik-cache/arm64/boot.oat (art_jni_trampoline+132)
```

I've search all over for people with similar issues, there are a few but they end up having JNI or odd frameworks that I don't use. I'm using only this:

```
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.1'
and
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.14'
```

the gradle build stuff:

```
compileSdkVersion 32
minSdkVersion 29
targetSdkVersion 32
```

any help would be appreciated on how to track this down.

Comment: Without the Java part of the stack trace I don't think anyone can help you. Also note that many parts of the standard library are implemented as native methods.

Comment: Yep, without the java part this seems impossible.  This is sort of a hail mary at this point. This has been very frustrating at the number of crashes just continues on this same thing.  I may need to consider pulling the app as the rating drop, and maybe create a fresh project in Android Studio. Much of this code is over 10 years old.

Comment: Did you find a root of problem? Same problem here.

Comment: unfortunately I still have the same issue. It's impacting my User-perceived crash rate. Months later and it's the exact same stacktrace and error. If you run into a solution please let me know!

Comment: Hello, I observe such problem mostly on Android 13 Samsung devices.  Could you please share you insights?